# A Binary Tree method

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a function which returns a tuple of list of leaf nodes and list of internal nodes for a binary tree.

So the way I tried doing it was to initialize two lists (one for leaf nodes and the other for internal nodes).

I've already written my code and it should work perfectly fine but there's only one issue. Since I have to do it recursively, I have to call the function in itself, which means that the initialization of the lists will take place again and that will simply reset the lists. This isn't what I want. I want to keep adding elements to those lists and return them eventually...

EDIT: I'm sorry, I can't add my code but I can give you the rough idea:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
if (leaf node reached):
            add leaf node to list1

else:
            add node to list2
            call the function on the left child
            call the function on the right child
return (leaves_data,internals_data)
```

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: What you usually do with recursive functions is you pass in the results you've got so far as a parameter into the function. Then you make a wrapper function without those parameters that calls the "real" function with the initial values.

Comment: Define a nested function where the initialization is done in the outer function and the inner function can access the lists via referencing the outer function's scope.

Comment: seems you should put the *run once* part of code outside the recursive function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each recursion step you initially create an empty list to store data only from that iteration. Then you call the recursive function which is expected to return other lists with more content. You append the returned list to your and you'll have a correct partial result to the relevant branch of the tree the recursive function is iterating. Finally, you return the merged list from the function, allowing the upper level of the tree append the result again and grow the result until it goes back to the root level.

This is called the recursion step and works as long as the base of the recursion (i.e. the rule that makes recursion stop) is correct.

```
def get_nodes(l):
    # Recursion base
    if l is None: return ([], [])
    if l.children is None: return ([], [l])

    # Recursion step
    this = ([l], [])
    internal, leaf = get_nodes(l.children.left)
    this[0] += internal
    this[1] += leaf

    internal, leaf = get_nodes(l.children.right)
    this[0] += internal
    this[1] += leaf

    return this
```

(Note: untested pseudo-code, just an example)

All the description above is conceptual and should be considered the trivial implementation. In practical implementations, however you would avoid creating and appending multiple lists many times. You can do this in your code by moving the lists to the global scope and using the global keyword to bind the global values to local variables.

Answer (score 0):

In some way, you should make sure that the initialization only happens once. There are different ways of doing this.

One way of doing it is by doing the initialization outside your function, let's say you have something like this (pseudo code):

```
function recursiveFunction():
    // Here you had your old init code, you don't need it here anymore
    // Here your function is the same as before
    // [ ... ]
    recursiveFunction()
    return; // Some return statement
end 

// Init stuff here (make sure these variables/list you init are globally defined, so they can be accessed from inside the function
// Then call your recursive function:
recursiveFunction()
```

Another easy (but not necessarily pretty way) of doing it is having some global variable outside that is set to true when the init has been done, for instance something like this:

```
global variable init_is_done = false // Make sure this can be accessed inside your function

function recursiveFunction():
    // Check if init_is_done is true before doing init
    if not init_is_done:
        // Have your init code here
        init_is_done = true
    endif

    // Here your function is the same as before
    // [ ... ]
    recursiveFunction()
    return; // Some return statement
end 

// Now you can just call your function
recursiveFunction()
```

According to which language you are using, different methods can be good. I would certainly try to have the init stuff outside the function. Hope this works out for you.